# Export html table into Excel on iPad through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, excel

Update:

This is the table that I've tried to export to Excel:

```
<div id="dvData">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Photo No.</th>
        <th>Vote Count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td id="result1" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td id="result2" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td id="result3" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td id="result4" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td id="result5" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td id="result6" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td id="result7" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td id="result8" class="results">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript that I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

            // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

                    var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
              type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
        });

        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
                    // HTML5 Blob        
        var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8' });
        var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        $(this)
                .attr({
                    'download': filename,
                    'href': csvUrl
                });
            } else {
        // Data URI
        var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

                    $(this)
            .attr({
                  'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
                });
    }
}

$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
});
});
```

The above javascript only exports a csv file on the desktop, however on the iOS devices, it just opens up another web page showing the table data. Is there a way to export it onto the iOS Excel app?

---

```
    <div id="box1">
        <span id="result1" class="results">0</span>
    </div>

    <div id="box2">
        <span id="result2" class="results">0</span>
    </div>
```

I currently have a click counter with the following JavaScript when you click on the box, the value will increase respectively.

```
$( function() {
var clickCount = localStorage.getItem('clickCount');
clickCount = clickCount ? parseInt(clickCount) : 0;
var $num = $('#result1');
$num.text(clickCount);
$('#box1').click( function() {
    $num.text(++clickCount);
    localStorage.setItem('clickCount', clickCount);
    document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = clickCount;
});
});
```

At the same time, I would like to export this value to the Excel app on the iPad, is there any way around this? The other solutions I've tried seems to only work for excel on the desktop.

Comment: *"The other solutions I've tried"* ... what other solutions? How do we know what was tried that didn't work?

Comment: @charlietfl My apologies, I've updated with a solution that I've tried that is able to export as .csv on the desktop. However, it does not work on the iPad. Greatly appreciate if you could suggest any ideas!